# Boost python not seeing memory is owned by smart pointer

Tags: c++, move, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, boost-python

I am getting a seg fault trigger when the destructor below destroys it's vector elements. Originally it was a `vector<Parent>` but I changed this to `vector<unique_ptr<Parent>>` and since then the crash occurs every time:

```
class Owner
{
    Owner() = default;
    ~Owner() = default;    // Seg faults

    void assignVec(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>& vec)
    {
        _vec = std::move(vec);
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> _vec;
};
```

Each vector element subtype is a polymorphic class, also inheriting from boost::python::wrapper

```
class Child: public Parent, public boost::python::wrapper<Parent>
{
    Child();
    virtual ~Child() = default;
};
```

where:

```
class Parent
{
    Parent() = default;
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
};
```

So the entire inheritance hierarchy does have virtual destructors.

GDB backtrace is showing:

```
#0  0x00007ffff636b207 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
#1  0x00007ffff636c8f8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007ffff63add27 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff64bf678 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:196
#3  0x00007ffff63b6489 in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=0x7ffff66fb760 <main_arena>, ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff64bcd31 "free(): invalid pointer", action=3) at malloc.c:5004
#4  _int_free (av=0x7ffff66fb760 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3843
#5  0x00007fffc373972f in Child::~Child (this=0x2742b10, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at Child.h:23
#6  0x000000000045694e in std::default_delete<Parent>::operator() (this=0x11922e0, __ptr=0x2742b10) at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:81
#7  0x0000000000454c27 in std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> >::~unique_ptr (this=0x11922e0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:274
#8  0x000000000045a882 in std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> > > (__pointer=0x11922e0) at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:98
#9  0x0000000000458f67 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> >*> (__first=0x11922e0, __last=0x11922e8) at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:108
#10 0x0000000000457636 in std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> >*> (__first=0x11922e0, __last=0x11922e8) at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:137
#11 0x000000000045584d in std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> >*, std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> > > (__first=0x11922e0, __last=0x11922e8)
    at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:206
#12 0x000000000049b53d in std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Parent, std::default_delete<Parent> > > >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffc4a8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:567
#13 0x000000000048c677 in Owner::~Owner (this=0x7fffffffc4a8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
```

Printing `this` in frame 5 does show a valid object. Frame 4 source code of free() is:

```
static void _int_free(mstate av, mchunkptr p, int have_lock)                      
{                                                                     
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T size;        /* its size */                         
  mfastbinptr*    fb;          /* associated fastbin */               
  mchunkptr       nextchunk;   /* next contiguous chunk */            
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T nextsize;    /* its size */                         
  int             nextinuse;   /* true if nextchunk is used */        
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T prevsize;    /* size of previous contiguous chunk */
  mchunkptr       bck;         /* misc temp for linking */            
  mchunkptr       fwd;         /* misc temp for linking */            

  const char *errstr = NULL;
  int locked = 0;

  size = chunksize(p);

  /* Little security check which won't hurt performance: the          
     allocator never wrapps around at the end of the address space.   
     Therefore we can exclude some size values which might appear
     here by accident or by "design" from some intruder.  */        
  if (__builtin_expect ((uintptr_t) p > (uintptr_t) -size, 0)    
      || __builtin_expect (misaligned_chunk (p), 0))
    {  
      errstr = "free(): invalid pointer";
    errout:      
      if (have_lock || locked)
        (void)mutex_unlock(&av->mutex);                               
      malloc_printerr (check_action, errstr, chunk2mem(p), av);      // CRASHES HERE
```

Does anyone have any advice how to proceed debugging this?

**UPDATE:**

I have created a small example in a unit test, creating `Owner` and a vector, calling `assignVec()` and the problem does not occur. However, once the vector is passed in, nothing else obtains the Parent memory.

**UPDATE2:**

We think the problem is with boost python needing to be informed of the smart pointer. Apparently Boost Python doesn't support unique_ptr and we're struggling to get it to recognize shared_ptr (both Boost and std), even using the typical register technique.

Comment: What are you doing with the class? Can you show a minimal example of usage of the class that triggers the seg fault? A simple definition without any instance surely does not

Comment: @Superlokkus it's very difficult if I am honest. The code is proprietary. The problem didn't exist until I changed the vector from Parent* to unique_ptr<Parent>

Comment: I will see if I can create a simple example in a unit test

Comment: @Superlokkus I just updated the code of Owner and added an update at the bottom.

Comment: What's line 23 of child.h?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz empty destructor/defaulted.

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `assignVec` that is able to reproduce the error. In particular, what happens to the caller's vector *after* the call to `assignVec`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you are giving and with the assumption `boost::python` has not a bug here I would guess your usage of moving semantics might be the cause:

```
void assignVec(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>& vec)
    {
        _vec = std::move(vec);
    }
```

Here you are moving from a l-value-reference to a vector, `vector&` to your member. Problem is: Usually one only moves from r-values references (`vector&&`) as they ca not accessed any more, because the only bind to temporaries or if the one explicitly acknowledges the moving by creating an r/x-values reference like you did by using `std::move`.

Problem is: I bet you caller of assignVec might not be aware of this, because then why did you not already use a r-value reference in the signature, so that the caller has to `std::move` explicitly? My assumption is, you caller does not, and is doing more than the one thing that is legal to moved from values: Destruct them.

Of course you ask yourself, why does it break then in the destructor? In my experience segmentation faults occur some expression after the cause, in this case I would say the undefined behaviour of the caller of `assignVec` by still using the vector given to `assignVec`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing this out. I am not much of an expert with move semantics. Should the signatures be &&? We also think the problem is with boost python needing to be informed of the smart pointer. Apparently Boost Python doesn't support unique_ptr and we're struggling to get it to recognize shared_ptr (both Boost and std).

Comment: Depends on how the function would be used, my general advice is: When in doubt just just a `const T&`. If you are concerned about performance add an overload for `T&&`. Or if you have or can have templated code use a forwarding reference (`template T&&`). I recommend https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=3435 for general default advice and explanation. 
I am not familiar with boost python in particular, but I guess you have over looked life time details boost python has to rely to you, because of the garbage collection and language i.e. runtime crossing to python.

Comment: In the case of non copyable elements of like `unique_ptr` in a vector, its more or less the same, with the difference you are more forced to decide how your function is intended to be used: Is the semantic idea behind your function that the caller should say goodbye to the passed objects? No problem either just use a `&&`,. Or does he should have a choice? Is shared_ptr an option? Why do you have to use dynamic storage duration? Why not let the vector handle the elements? Why not let class owner construct them?! All things you need context for. Thats design.

Comment: I used move semantics because a second instance of Owner will be created and the first Owner will pass it's terminal state to the new Owner.

Comment: Then its something between these two Owner instances, no the one using them, meaning it should not be a public function but should be done in the move constructor or move assignment operator of the owner class. And luckily for you, you don't even have to write it yourself, usually the compiler automatically generates  it for you. And in the cases the compiler is not sure, you can reassure him by just saying move-ctor = default; and so on. (See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) So in your case just move assign the Owner instance and you are done.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated: the first Owner passing state to the second Owner is new functionality, not the functionality causing the bug. The bug is being caused when Owner's destructor is trying to delete it's vector of unique_ptr objects, of which are Boost Python objects and we think the Python runtime is deleting the object before the C++ destructor, which then tries to delete an already-deleted object.

Comment: Well possible but for me just speculation without the full code. So either you post full reproducing code here or we have come do a dead end. Besides that this question without reproducing code but speculation won't help other readers.